# HTML5 Video Javascript

Tags: html5-video

I am not experienced in Javascript, I have the following script to play video files on Andriod phone, and it works fine.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function PlayMyVideo(arg) {
            var myVideo = document.getElementById([arg]);
            myVideo.play();
        }
    </script>
<video id="what" src="what.mp4" poster="" />
<input type="button" onclick="PlayMyVideo('what')" value="Play" />
```

I am trying to write the  tag on the fly:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function PlayVideo() {
            new_video = document.createElement('video');
            new_video.setAttribute('scr', 'what.mp4'); 
            new_video.play(); 
         }
    </script>
<input type="button" onclick="PlayVideo()" value="Play2" />
```

Nothing happen, would appreciate your suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
new_video.setAttribute('scr', 'what.mp4');
```

'scr' is misspelled. It should be 'src'.

and also you should wait for the movie to load before play

Answer (score 2):

Well you're not appending the newly created tag to anything, so it can't play because it's in "memory"/"void", not on the screen.

```
<div id='plc'>&nbsp;</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function PlayVideo() {
new_video = document.createElement('video');
document.getElementById('plc').appendChild(new_video);
new_video.setAttribute('scr', 'what.mp4');
new_video.play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it created the video element; however the video did not play.

Comment: that's strange, maybe changing new_video.play() to window.onload = function() { new_video.play(); } would help

Comment: Thanks Slawek, it did not work at first, then I changed ' to " for the scr and the original script you gave me first worked great but on iPad not on Android.

Comment: Just as a follow up, this tag works well on Android:<video src="what.mp4"  onclick="this.play();"/>.  Since I have a number of video clips, I thought it will be more efficient to make it as javascript were I can use variable for the clip name.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you are creating the video element, you need to add it to the DOM before it will be visible, more info here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml