# HTML5 Video tag for Android Phones

Tags: android, html, video, html5-video

I am breaking my head with this html5 video tag for the  past few hours.
I have checked the answers in this site and nothing works for me.

I want to load a video file on andriod phones version 2.3 and above.
Any help will be highly appreciatable.
I took code from this url:
[HTML5 Video Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532553/html5-video-javascript)

My Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PlayVideo() {
        new_video = document.createElement('video');
        new_video.setAttribute('scr', 'Work.mp4'); 
        window.onload = function() { new_video.play(); } 
        //new_video.play(); 
     }
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="PlayVideo()" value="Play2" />
```

Kindly help me with this code.
And one more question, will andriod versions 2+ supports HTML5 video tag?

Thanks 
Haan

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that the second line of your `PlayVideo` function was a typo (specifically trying to set a `scr` attribute instead of a `src` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

As we already discussed in one other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711078/1108032) there seems to be no soltion that work on all 2.3 devices using pure HTML 5 (I, together with many others, had problems on making the solution of the thread working in Nexus One). I found a solution that seems to work on all devices, but it also needs adding of some native code. Please consider [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952025/1108032) to the above thread.